# WinDbg is not loading my symbol files

Tags: windbg, symbols

I'm writing a Kernel mode usb-driver primary for Windows Vista 32bit but hopefully it will also be able to be builded for Win XP, Win Vista, Win 7 32 and 64 bit.

Anyway, I'm debugging from an Windows 7 32bit laptop to a Windows Vista 32bit laptop (the target). The laptops are connected via Firewire and the connection seams to be ok since I can set some breakpoints and step trough parts of my code. All information is in assembly though and WinDbg says "Your debugger is not using the correct symbols..." when I hover over an function in my driver.

Symbol file path is:
SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\Me\MyDriver\objchk_wlh_x86\i386

Source file path is:
C:\Me\MyDriver

Everything is newly compiled but WinDgb still won't accept my symbol files. Why?

Comment: Does C:\Me\MyDriver\objchk_wlh_x86\i386 contain your application's pdb file?

Answer (score 1):

If you can set breakpoints and step through your code it sounds like your symbols are fine. You can try:

!itoldyouso mydriver

If you want the debugger to convince you that your symbols are OK.

I never use the hover feature in the GUI, but it's entirely possible that it just doesn't work properly in some cases.

-scott

Comment: It turned out there was a mismatch with my driver and symbol files. Deleted folder \objchk_whl_x86\ rebuilded everything and then it worked. I found the fault using the command "!sym noisy" 
 (http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html)

Comment: New problem though... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245473/windbg-c-level-debugging

Comment: this might be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560260(v=vs.85).aspx