# WinDbg c-level debugging?

Tags: c, windbg

Just started to step my kernel mode usb driver and it is in assembler. How do I configure WinDbg to c-level debugging? This is how i looks now =/

```
MyDriver!MyDriver_EvtDeviceAdd+0xb:
af20801b 833d647020af03  cmp     dword ptr [MyDriver!DebugLevel (af207064)],3
0: kd> p
MyDriver!MyDriver_EvtDeviceAdd+0x2e:
af20803e ff15006020af    call    dword ptr [MyDriver!_imp__KeGetCurrentIrql (af206000)]
0: kd> p
MyDriver!MyDriver_EvtDeviceAdd+0x58:
af208068 8d95a8feffff    lea     edx,[ebp-158h]
0: kd> p
MyDriver!MyDriver_EvtDeviceAdd+0x64:
af208074 c785bcfeffff508420af mov dword ptr [ebp-144h],offset MyDriver!MyDriver_EvtDevicePrepareHardware (af208450)
```

Answer (score 2):

WinDbg cannot find pdb files. Fill properly all WinDbg paths:

1. Symbol search path - must include driver .pdb files and local path for MS debugging symbols.
2. Source search path - must include directory with driver source files.
3. Image file path - must contain driver .sys file.

Look at WinDbg log: it reports all errors trying to load debug information. If you see something like "Cannot load debug information for your_driver.sys", something is wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 1. and 2. is ok. But I have to look closer to 3. tomorrow. I'm running the driver on a target computer connected to my developer computer via Firewire. On the target computer I only got the .sys file (and an inf for installing and some WDK KMDF co-installers dll's). The developer computer have the complete sourcecode, generated symbols ets...) Is that a correct way?

Comment: @user872661 - target computer must contain only runtime: .sys, .inf. Debugger computer must contain .pdb, symbol, source code and executable. When driver is loaded, open one of its source files and try to set breakpoint. WindDbg asks you whether to load debug symbols. Select "Yes". This is is place when debugging symbols are loaded, look at WinDbg log - it prints all loaded drivers.

Comment: Ok, since I'm able to break on breakpoints I guess the symbol files are ok. Still there is only assembler code while stepping =/

Answer (score 1):

Your symbols look fine based on the output above. If you're not getting your source window popping up, you're typically in one of two cases:

1) You've moved your source code from where you originally built it. By default, the PDBs have the fully qualified path to the orignal source code location. If you move it, WinDBG won't be able to find it. You can see where WinDBG is looking by doing:

u MyDriver!MyDriver_EvtDeviceAdd

That should give you the full path of the source module containing that function embedded in the PDB. You can override this path by setting your Source Search Path to point to the new location.

2) You've managed to hide the source window somehow. Seems silly, but happens to my students all the time :) Check under the "Window" menu item in WinDBG to see if the window is open somewhere.

To clarify an earlier point, you do *not* need to set your Image File Path in this case. The only time that is required is if you're debugging a mini-dump.

-scott

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you are generating "Codeview"/debug symbols for your driver, and the file generated is accessible to Windbg.

Comment: I'm using WDK's own compiler and linker for Windows Vista x86 "checked-build" "build -ceZ" should I add any extra to that. My Windows Vista is a "free-build" is that a problem?